# How is setup_module() different from top-level statements in py.test?

Tags: python

If I don't have any teardown, do I need to use setup_module, or can I just use top-level statements?

```
=== test_1.py ===
foo = 3
def test_foo(): assert foo == 3

=== test_2.py 
def setup_module(m): m.foo = 3
def test_foo(): assert foo == 3
```

Will py.test execute all the top-level statements in order, and before it executes the first test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like py.test will evaluate your top-level-statements before any test, so `test_1.py` will work.

However, when you are writing tests, it is generally not a good idea to have any top-level-statements. You should try to structure your tests into Test Cases (a Class that holds your related test code) and which tests specific features of your application. So, if you take your code (`test_2.py`) and turn it into a Test Case, it will look something like this:

```
def setup_module(module):
    module.TestFoo.foo = 3

class TestFoo:
    def test_foo(self):
        assert self.foo == 3
```

This way, you can keep adding all the related tests to `TestFoo` and even add more than one `TestCase` per module (although it's usually best to have each `TestCase` in it's own file).

Regarding your `teardown_module` question, you only need a *teardown* when you need to restore the application state to its initial state (removing newly created items, etc) or to clean up hanging connections (closing files, sockets, etc). In this case, since your `setup_module` is not doing anything that needs any clean up, *teardown* is not needed and py.test won't complain the lack of it.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on why it is not a good idea to have top-level statements? If it is usually best to have each TestCase in it's own file, what do I get in return for the extra layer added by the class? thanks!

Comment: top-level are usually not good in _test files_ because we have the ability to use Test Cases. You can learn more about Test Cases and Python unit testing in general,  by looking at the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html. If you still have more questions, let me know.

Comment: Test cases were organized as classes originally because the languages they were first written in by Beck & Gamma offered no alternative (Smalltalk, Java). Python does have alternatives, so I was just wondering if you or someone else had worked out guidelines for when the overhead of putting tests into classes is justified. Thanks anyway.